# ASP.NET change in the content of the asp-page

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a iframe in the site, and I want to add a specific text into url.. But I would like to know how I can respond to the url of the site..

`How can I add`<%= %> into the url,
Iam using forms, how should I be able to return the url

FOr example

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<% %> &amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this is to build the iframe html tag in runtime and then add it to a control like Literal. There are much more ways but I think this is the best way for you.

Hope it helps

Comment: THis is not what I asked, I would like knwo how to return the URL using <%=  %> in the aspx page

Comment: If I understood correctly, the following should solve your problem: <%=Request.RawUrl %>

Comment: okej,, well it doesen't work to type request in the aspx-file